# How to perform basic operations with std::atomic when the type is not Integral?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdatomic

To be precise, I only need to increase a double by another double and want it to be thread safe. I don't want to use mutex for that since the execution speed would dramatically decrease.

Comment: related: [Atomic double floating point or SSE/AVX vector load/store on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055402/atomic-double-floating-point-or-sse-avx-vector-load-store-on-x86-64).  Basically the same answer as this, but with x86 asm details.  (Some compilers are fairly inefficient getting data from XMM to integer for `compare_exchange` or even load/store with `atomic<double>`, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As a rule, the C++ standard library tries to provide only operations that can be implemented efficiently. For `std::atomic`, that means operations that can be performed lock-free in an instruction or two on "common" architectures. "Common" architectures have atomic fetch-and-add instructions for integers, but not for floating point types.

If you want to implement math operations for atomic floating point types, you'll have to do so yourself with a CAS (compare and swap) loop ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bee48498c23acb01)):

```
std::atomic<double> foo{0};

void add_to_foo(double bar) {
  auto current = foo.load();
  while (!foo.compare_exchange_weak(current, current + bar))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, I didn't realize that in order to do that (add two doubles thread safely) I would need such dirty (or at least it looks like it to me) workaround.

Comment: I am a little confused. Why will this code not go into an infinite loop if foo != current due to foo being modified by another thread between the load and the CAS?

Comment: @Joe `compare_exchange_weak` takes its first argument by reference, and updates it to the observed value on failure. So if the CAS fails becayse `foo != current` the loop calculates a new `current + bar` from the updated `current` and tries again.

Comment: @Casey Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

So use the integral atomic as a memory barrier. Here's a page with source and explanation: http://preshing.com/20121019/this-is-why-they-call-it-a-weakly-ordered-cpu/

Comment: A memory barrier only helps with ordering, not atomicity.  This is why you need a CAS (or LL/SC) to make the entire read-modify-write atomic.