# Add atomic<double> and double

Tags: c++, double, atomic

I want to add two values:

```
auto size = new std::atomic<double>(0);
double packet_size = 64e3;
*size += packet_size;
```

But I got an error.

```
no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::atomic<double>’ and ‘double’)
```

How should I correctly add these two numbers?

Comment: `std::atomic<Floating>` is not to appear until C++20. You got a compiler supporting it?

Comment: @DeiDei; not even complaining... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24b749dce3f8d705

Comment: You may want to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116279/how-to-perform-basic-operations-with-stdatomic-when-the-type-is-not-integral

Comment: @user1810087 That uses `operator+`, so it implicitly converts the `atomic<double>` to `double`, adds them together, and assigns back to the atomic variable. That's kind of not atomic.

Comment: new ...? Why that?

Comment: @manni66 to pass pointer to another thread.

Comment: You can take the address of a variable.

Comment: @ is it better?

Answer (score 2):

Even tough you can create `atomic<float>` and `atomic<double>`, atomic operators are not defined for floating point atomics.  This is because there is no x86 (nor ARM) assembly instruction for atomically add floating point values.

A workaround is to use the compare_exchange operations to increment/change your atomic variable.

```
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> i{};
    i += 3;

    //  Peter Cordes pointed out in a comment below that using 
    //  compare_exchange_weak() may be better suited for most 
    //  uses.
    //  Then again, the needed strength of the exchange depends 
    //  on your application, and the hardware it's intended to run on.  

    std::atomic<double> f{};
    for (double g = f; !f.compare_exchange_strong(g, g + 1.0);)
      ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using a loop already, use `compare_exchange_weak` so it compiles more nicely on LL/SC ISAs like ARM.  Otherwise this compiles to a nested loop on ARM.  Like most RISC, ARM doesn't have instructions to do any atomic RMW except a paired load/store-conditional, with the ALU operation implemented however you want.